# Регулярное выражение в if

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, shell

Необходимо из всех файлов в директории, найти только те, что начинаются на "P" заканчивается на ".JPG", и подправить мета-данные.
Загуглив, нашел сравнить по первому символу и по последнему, как склеить вместе не знаю.

```
#!/bin/bash
find * -type f | while read j; do
file="${j##*/}"
if [[ $file =~ ^P ]] #^P  ???  .JPG* 
    then
        echo "$j"
        #exiftool -AllDates+=8760:00 -overwrite_original $j
        #exiftool -DateTimeOriginal $j
        echo "   "
fi
done
```

Comment: А разве в bash регулярки отличаются от общепринятых? `^P.*\.jpg$` - в начале `P`, а в конце `.jpg`.

Comment: @Visman большое спасибо!

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов оформите, пожалуйста, ответ на Ваш вопрос как ответ, а не как часть вопроса. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @ReinRaus прошу прощение, впервые вопрос задаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно сразу искать нужные файлы:

```
find * -type f -name P\*.JPG | ...
```

и, к слову, имя файла можно отделить от пути к нему так:

```
file=$(basename "$j")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: `if [[ $file =~ ^P.*\.JPG$ ]]`